# VBA - Type mismatch - code?

Tags: vba

I've been playing around with this code in various permutations trying to get something to work.  The first half of the if statement is functioning, but in the event that the sum of the range is 0, the code is not performing the desired calculation.  I'm getting a "type mismatch" error.

Any thoughts?

```
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To n
    If Application.Sum(Sheets(i).Range("O13:O33")) > 0 Then
    Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("P13:P19").Value
    Else
    Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("I13:I19") - (4 * Sheets(i).Range("K13:K19"))
    End If
Next i
```

Best regards.

Comment: You can't do math on a multi cell range.  The first is basically moving an array, but you will need to cycle through the range and do the math on each cell one at a time.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner ... so after the else statement I should attempt some sort of loop to perform the calculation is what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do math on a multi cell range.

The first is basically moving an array, but you will need to cycle through the range and do the math on each cell one at a time.

```
Dim Rng As Range
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To n
        If Application.Sum(Sheets(i).Range("O13:O33")) > 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(13, i), .Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("P13:P19").Value
        Else
            For Each Rng In .Range(.Cells(13, i), .Cells(19, i))
                Rng.Value = Sheets(i).Cells(Rng.Row, "I") - (4 * Sheets(i).Cells(Rng.Row, "K"))
            Next Rng
        End If
    Next i
End With
```